# Should I ask about security testing during an upcoming client meeting?

Tags: management, manager, clients

**Background:**

- My manager emailed me about a potential client who might be hiring us to do test automation as well as security testing before my manager went onto her holiday.
- I am meeting this client to discuss test automation scopes this Friday.
- I have had some experience in security testing but officially I am a test automation guy.
- We have a security test specialist but he is not locally based and he is extremely busy.

**My question:**

- I want to ask this client about security testing scopes as well during our meeting, but I am unsure if this is within my responsibilities. From what I can see, I may bring more business into our company but it looks like I am stepping out of the line.

**My approach:**

- I want to email my manager and ask her about it if she does not object I will bring it up during our meeting.
- Or I do not do anything at all.

Comment: So ask your manager. I don't really see what the question is here. Only your manager or someone else at your company can tell you whether this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it's a bad idea to preempt your managers role. If you're the expert in one field you should focus on that to start with, but be prepared to field questions and give contact information (or the managers contact details) in other fields if asked.